# What is the best method for determining a users location?

Tags: geolocation, location, ip-geolocation

I read a few other posts on SO that came close to what I was looking for, but I'm basically looking for a service to provide accurate GeoLocation services that will get you close to a location.

We used one IP based service that plotted us 4 hours away. That's no good. What is the most accurate service outside of the HTML5 GeoLocation API?

Answer (score 0):

You will find both free & paid services for this: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/03/31/3-free-ways-to-geolocate-by-ip/

MaxMind is the better known series that works well at the City level.

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should ask. There was a /. article on this subject just a few days ago. Here is an [article by Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/pinpointing_a_c.html) on it. Very interesting (and disturbing) stuff.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5, it gives you coordinates Latitude and longitude that you can send to a google map an get the map location.

http://html5demos.com/geo

but works only in newest browsers..

Comment: HTML5 works for most 50% of our users. We are looking for a solution to cover the other 50%. :)